# Laravel ReflectionException

Tags: php, laravel

I have a class called CustomerController with a delete function:

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
```

{

```
public function getAllCustomer()
{

    return \App\model\Customer::get();

}

public function destroy (Customer $id)
{
    $id->delete();
}
```

This is the route:

```
Route::delete('customer/{id}' , 'CustomerController@destroy');
```

I get this error:

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Customer does not exist
```

I already tried Composer update and Composer dump-autoload with no success.

A screenshot:
[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: add error sreenshot

Comment: Don't forget to add `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` in your `CustomerController ` page .

Comment: @J.Doe added a screenshot

Comment: @Ashraf It's already included

Comment: What about `App\Customer` as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not include classes using [`use` statements](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php), php will try to find the class in the current namespace.

So, the function `function destroy (Customer $id)` will look for the class `Customer` in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. To avoid this, add a use statement for the `App\model\Customer` class above on top of your controller class. For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\model\Customer;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function getAllCustomer()
    {
        return Customer::get();
    }

    public function destroy (Customer $id)
    {
        $id->delete();
    }
}
```

Now you can also use a shorter name in the `getAllCustomer()` function.

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this as the answer so other users might also find the solution.

Comment: Of Course! Thank you very much again!

Comment: @Boby this is exactly as my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
return \App\model\Customer::get();
```

to this:

add namespace at the top:

```
use App\Customer;

return Customer::get();
```

as you are using route model binding on delete action by injecting `Customer` class to the method therfore its failing so make sure you add model namespace at the top of the file(CustomerController).

The error is happening beacuse `CustomerController` is trying to look for `Customer` model in controllers namespace which means that your model namespace is wrong.

Comment: Now Im getting "class App\Customer" doesnt exist

Comment: @Boby go to folder app and look for a class `Customer.php` see if its there then do a composer dump-autoload